# phishing or pharming incident

Tags: phishing

I would like to know the REASONS / CAUSES why I am being redirected to another website when I log on to an ONLINE BANKING website. The following are the details/observations from my experience:

1. I knew that it is a phishing/not authentic website because it asks me for ADDITIONAL log-in details like my ATM CARD NO. and PIN NO.  My online banking site only asks for USERNAME and PASSWORD.
2. When I use a different Internet Service Provider, I am not being redirected to the phishing site.

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: On the other ISP, are you using the same computer?

Comment: What exactly is farming? If you are being redirect your infected.

Comment: chipperyman573: yes, I am using the same computer. What would be the reason why I'm being redirected? Thank you!

Comment: Mmm... Good question. But I believe it belongs in http://security.stackexchange.com/ You would get more good answers there

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, because you have asked _why_ is this happening. It is more of advice to you. Get in touch with your ISP. it might be that ISP server got attacked and all traffic addressed to your online banking website is redirected to malicious website. You may be not the only one effected by the issue, and you would do the right thing if you report it.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely an attack and you'd be wise to not enter any details (as you've already noticed).  Most people are oblivious to this sort of attack so kudo's on your part.  If you have windows 7 or earlier operating system run this http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix

If you have windows 8 however, we'll have to find a different tool as this doesn't work with windows 8 yet I don't believe.  This has been my goto malware removal tool for quite a while, it's excellent, far better than anything else I've ever used.  It can take 5-15 minutes to run though so if it's taking it's sweet time, be patient.  The attack may not be on your machine though as smc mentioned.  It's considered a man in the middle attack which in this case is redirecting you to a fake site in an attempt to get your cc info.  If it finds nothing, it's still possible there's something on your machine that combofix hasn't learned to detect yet but I doubt that'd be the case.  More likely a machine between you and the bank is compromised and contacting your isp would be the next step for me.

It also sorta sounded like you were using random public wifi to get online.  Maybe the person you're connected to is infected (or purposely being the attacker -- which in my view you deserve for stealing wifi!)